# how to run a gazebo world file

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how do i run the *.world files in gazebo_worlds/worlds?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11472/how-to-run-a-gazebo-world-file/) by [mmyself](https://answers.ros.org/users/1194/mmyself/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2011-10-08

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at this link to an article on my blog, it should help you.

http://mobotica.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-gazebo.html

As an alternative you can also use

```
roscore
```

and then

```
rosrun gazebo gazebo /path/to/.world file
```

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2011-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmyself](https://answers.ros.org/users/1194/mmyself/) on 2011-10-09**:
thx, thats it.

**Comment by [Abdulbaki](https://answers.ros.org/users/31967/abdulbaki/) on 2018-03-18**:
rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo src/mst_robot/worlds/jackal_race.world
This worked for me.